# Better than brute force algorithms for a coin-flipping game

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem and I feel like there should be a well-known algorithm for solving it that's better than just brute force, but I can't think of one, so I'm asking here.

**The problem is as follows:** given `n` sorted (from low to high) lists containing `m` probabilities, choose one index for each list such that the sum of the chosen indexes is less than `m`. Then, for each list, we flip a coin, where the chance of it landing heads is equal to the probability at the chosen index for that list. Maximize the chance of the coin landing heads at least once.

**Are there any algorithms for solving this problem that are better than just brute force?**

This problem seems most similar to the knapsack problem, except the value of the items in the knapsack isn't merely a sum of the items in the knapsack. (Written in Python, instead of `sum(p for p in chosen_probabilities)` it's `1 - math.prod([1 - p for p in chosen_probabilities])`) And, there's restrictions on what items you can add given what items are already in the knapsack. For example, if the `index = 3` item for a particular list is already in the knapsack, then adding in the item with `index = 2` for that same list isn't allowed (since you can only pick one index for each list). So there are certain items that can and can't be added to the knapsack based on what items are already in it.

<strike>Linear optimization won't work because the values in the lists don't increase linearly, the final coin probability isn't linear with respect to the chosen probabilities, and our constraint is on the sum of the indexes, rather than the values in the lists themselves.</strike> As David has pointed out, linear optimization *will* work if you use binary variables to pick out the indexes and a logarithm to deal with the non-linearity.

EDIT:

I've found that explaining the motivation behind this problem can be helpful for understanding it. Imagine you have 10 seconds to solve a problem, and three different ways to solve it. You have models of how likely it is that each method will solve the problem, given how many seconds you try that method for, but if you switch methods, you lose all progress on the one you were previously trying. What methods should you try and for how long?

Comment: Are you obliged to select one index in each list, or can you select a subset of these lists?

Comment: One index for each list (though of course selecting index 0 is basically the same thing as not selecting an index for that list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximizing `1 - math.prod([1 - p for p in chosen_probabilities])` is equivalent to minimizing `math.prod([1 - p for p in chosen_probabilities])`, which is equivalent to minimizing the log of this objective, which is a linear function of 0-1 indicator variables, so you could do an integer programming formulation this way.

I can't promise that this will be much better than brute force. The problem is that `math.log(1 - p)` is well approximated by `-p` when `p` is close to zero. My intuition is that for nontrivial instances it will be qualitatively similar to using integer programming to solve subset sum, which doesn't go particularly well.

If you're willing to settle for a bicriteria approximation scheme (get an answer such that the sum of the chosen indexes is less than m, that is at least as good as the best answer summing to less than (1 − ε) m) then you can round up the probability to multiples of ε and use dynamic programming to get an algorithm that runs in time polynomial in n, m, 1/ε.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code for [David Eisenstat's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66460442/5049813).

To understand the implementation, I think it helps to go through the math first.

As a reminder, there are `n` lists, each with `m` options. (In the motivating example at the bottom of the question, each list represents a method for solving the problem, and you are given `m-1` seconds to solve the problem. Each list is such that `list[index]` gives the chance of solving the problem with that method if the method is run for `index` seconds.)

We let the lists be stored in a matrix called `d` (named `data` in the code), where each row in the matrix is a list. (And thus each column represents an index, or, if following the motivating example, an amount of time.)

The probability of the coin landing heads, given that we chose index `j*` for list `i`, is computed as

[image: coin landing heads]

We would like to maximize this.

(To explain the stats behind this equation, we're computing 1 minus the probability that the coin doesn't land on heads. The probability that the coin doesn't land on heads is the probability that each flip doesn't land on heads. The probability that a single flip doesn't land on heads is just 1 minus the probability that does land on heads. And the probability it does land on heads is the number we've chosen, `d[i][j*]`. Thus, the total probability that all the flips land on tails is just the product of the probability that each one lands on tails. And then the probability that the coin lands on heads is just 1 minus the probability that all the flips land on tails.)

Which, as David pointed out, is the same as minimizing:

[image: first min]

Which is the same as minimizing:

[image: second min]

Which is equivalent to:

[image: third min]

Then, since this is linear sum, we can turn it into an integer program.

We'll be minimizing:

[image: goal]

This lets the computer choose the indexes by allowing it to create an `n` by `m` matrix of 1s and 0s called `x` where the 1s pick out particular indexes. We'll then define rules so that it doesn't pick out invalid sets of indexes.

The first rule is that you have to pick out an index for each list:

[image: one per rule]

The second rule is that you have to respect the constraint that the indexes chosen must sum to m or less:

[image: index sum rule]

And that's it! Then we can just tell the computer to minimize that sum according to those rules. It will spit out an `x` matrix with a single `1` on each row to tell us which index it has picked for the list on that row.

In code (using the motivating example), this is implemented as:

```
'''
Requirements:
cvxopt==1.2.6
cvxpy==1.1.10
ecos==2.0.7.post1
numpy==1.20.1
osqp==0.6.2.post0
qdldl==0.1.5.post0
scipy==1.6.1
scs==2.1.2
'''

import math
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# number of methods
n = 3

# if you have 10 seconds, there are 11 options for each method (0 seconds, 1 second, ..., 10 seconds)
m = 11

# method A has 30% chance of working if run for at least 3 seconds
# equivalent to [0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
A_list = [0, 0, 0] + [0.3] * (m - 3)

# method B has 30% chance of working if run for at least 3 seconds
# equivalent to [0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
B_list = [0, 0, 0] + [0.3] * (m - 3)

# method C has 40% chance of working if run for 4 seconds, 30% otherwise
# equivalent to [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
C_list = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3] + [0.4] * (m - 4)

data = [A_list, B_list, C_list]

# do the logarithm
log_data = []
for row in data:
    log_row = []
    for col in row:
        # deal with domain exception
        if col == 1:
            new_col = float('-inf')
        else:
            new_col = math.log(1 - col)
        log_row.append(new_col)
    log_data.append(log_row)

log_data = np.array(log_data)

x = cp.Variable((n, m), boolean=True)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(log_data, x)))

# the current solver doesn't work with equalities, so each equality must be split into two inequalities.
# see https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/1112
one_choice_per_method_constraint = [cp.sum(x[i]) <= 1 for i in range(n)] + [cp.sum(x[i]) >= 1 for i in range(n)]

# constrain the solution to not use more time than is allowed
# note that the time allowed is (m - 1), not m, because time is 1-indexed and the lists are 0-indexed
js = np.tile(np.array(list(range(m))), (n, 1))
time_constraint = [cp.sum(cp.multiply(js, x)) <= m - 1, cp.sum(cp.multiply(js, x)) >= m - 1]
constraints = one_choice_per_method_constraint + time_constraint

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve()

def compute_probability(data, choices):
    # compute 1 - ((1 - p1) * (1 - p2) * ...)
    return 1 - np.prod(np.add(1, -np.multiply(data, choices)))

print("Choices:")
print(x.value)

'''
Choices:
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
'''

print("Chance of success:")
print(compute_probability(data, x.value))

'''
Chance of success:
0.7060000000000001
'''
```

And there we have it! The computer has correctly determined that running method A for 3 seconds, method B for 3 seconds, and method C for 4 seconds is optimal. (Remember that the `x` matrix is 0-indexed, while the times are 1-indexed.)

Thank you, David, for the suggestion!