# Stop GLPK from printing log messages when using cvxpy

Tags: python, cvxpy

**I don't want my code to print anything to the terminal.**

Right now, the line I'm running is:

`prob.solve(cp.GLPK_MI, glpk={'msg_lev': 'GLP_MSG_OFF'}, verbosity=False)`

And it's displaying the text:

> Long-step dual simplex will be used

I've looked at [this](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/251) (which has been closed) and [this](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/351#issuecomment-293375008) (which doesn't seem to work) so far, but don't know the right options to pass to get the code to not print anything.

**How can I stop the GLPK solver from displaying text?**

If you want an example to test it for yourself, below is my full runnable example code (which can be understood by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66463230/5049813)):

```
'''
Requirements.txt:
cvxopt==1.2.6
cvxpy==1.1.10
ecos==2.0.7.post1
numpy==1.20.1
osqp==0.6.2.post0
qdldl==0.1.5.post0
scipy==1.6.1
scs==2.1.2
'''
from typing import List
import math
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

def solve(mech_data: List[List[float]], max_time_limit) -> List[int]:

    # number of mechanisms
    n = len(mech_data)

    # for a max time limit of 10, you need slots for each mech for time=0 and time=10
    # ...and everything in between which is 10 + 1 = 11 slots
    m = max_time_limit + 1

    log_data = []
    # log the data for the formula
    for row in mech_data:
        log_row = []
        for col in row:
            if col == 1:
                new_col = float('-inf')
            else:
                new_col = math.log(1 - col)

            log_row.append(new_col)
        log_data.append(log_row)

    log_data = np.array(log_data)

    x = cp.Variable((n, m), boolean=True)
    objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(log_data, x)))

    # the current solver doesn't work with equalities, so each equality must be split into two inequalities.
    # see https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/1112
    one_choice_per_mech_constraint = [cp.sum(x[i]) <= 1 for i in range(n)] + [cp.sum(x[i]) >= 1 for i in range(n)]

    # constrain the solution to the real time
    js = np.tile(np.array(list(range(m))), (n, 1))
    time_constraint = [cp.sum(cp.multiply(js, x)) <= max_time_limit, cp.sum(cp.multiply(js, x)) >= max_time_limit]
    constraints = one_choice_per_mech_constraint + time_constraint

    prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
    # THIS SHOULD NOT PRINT ANYTHING
    prob.solve(cp.GLPK_MI, glpk={'msg_lev': 'GLP_MSG_OFF'}, verbosity=False)
    # >> Long-step dual simplex will be used
    return list(np.argmax(x.value, axis=1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = 11

    # has 30% chance of working if run at least 3 times
    A_list = [0, 0, 0] + [0.3] * (m - 3)

    # has 30% chance of working if run at least 3 times
    B_list = [0, 0, 0] + [0.3] * (m - 3)

    # has 40% chance of working if run 4 times, 30% otherwise
    C_list = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3] + [0.4] * (m - 4)

    data = [A_list, B_list, C_list]

    ans = solve(data, m-1)
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to pass in `glpk={'msg_lev': 'GLP_MSG_OFF'}`, `verbose=False` tells `cvxpy` [to set the exact same option](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/c88f09215252c932c101c842dd684a60c16ea4cf/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/conic_solvers/glpk_mi_conif.py#L51-L60).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the message is generated by GLPK 4.65, regardless of the `GLP_MSG_*` option used.

However, it appears that version 5.0 has fixed this, see [this glpk-help mailing-list message from the library maintainer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glpk/2018-03/msg00000.html):

> To fix the bug please replace lines 923-930 in glpk/src/draft/glpios03.c
>
> ```c
> #if 1 /* 16/III-2016 */
>       if (((glp_iocp *)T->parm)->flip)
> #if 0 /* 20/I-2018 */
>          xprintf("WARNING: LONG-STEP DUAL SIMPLEX WILL BE USED\n");
> #else
>          xprintf("Long-step dual simplex will be used\n");
> #endif
> #endif
> ```
>
> with the following ones:
>
> ```c
> #if 1 /* 01/III-2018 */
>       if (((glp_iocp *)T->parm)->flip)
>         if (T->parm->msg_lev >= GLP_MSG_ALL)
>             xprintf("Long-step dual simplex will be used\n");
> #endif
> ```
>
> Please note that this change will appear in the next release of glpk.

The “next release” is 5.0, and only was [published in December 2020](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2020-12/msg00007.html) and the cvxopt wheels [have not yet been updated](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt-wheels/blob/ae8e6d0f806e2e849977a23f25f70084fad267c2/library_builders.sh#L5).

I’ve requested an update, see [issue #8](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt-wheels/issues/8) in the cvxopt wheels project.

Alternatively, you could [build cvxopt from source](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html#building-and-installing-from-source), at which point you just make sure it is built with the new release or with a version of GLPK with the code that produces the message disabled.